# Cannot save multi-select dropdown value to the database

Tags: php, laravel, multi-select, implode

I want to save multi-select dropdown value to the database.

Here is blade.php

```
 <select name="namedropdown[]" id="namedropdown" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Nothing selected</option>
        @foreach ($tdropdown as $tdrop)
        <option value="{{$tdrop}}">{{$tdrop}}</option>
        @endforeach
 </select>
```

[image]

Here is save function in controller

```
public function empstore(Request $request){

$employee = new employee();

$employee->namedropdown = $request->input('namedropdown');
$employee->namedropdown = implode(',', $employee->namedropdown);

$employee->save();
return redirect()->route('employee.index')->with('success','Data Added');

}
```

From my code it comes error as `Array to string conversion`

Please help me to **save multi-select dropdown value to the database**. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share us a dd of your ``$request->input('namedropdown')` ?

Comment: show `var_dump($_POST['namedropdown']);` ?

Comment: Try using serialize($request->input('namedropdown')) when importing to DB, and unserialize when you need to convert to array again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to assign the `$request->input('namedropdown')` into the model.

Try this code:

```php
public function empstore(Request $request){

$employee = new employee();
$employee->namedropdown = implode(',', $request->input('namedropdown'));

$employee->save();

return redirect()->route('employee.index')
    ->with('success','Data Added');
}
```

P.S.: You should improve your code style according the PSR1, PSR2 and PSR12. Methods must be camel-cased, class-names must be upper-camel-cased.

Answer (score 2):

This line here looks wrong

```
$employee->namedropdown = $request->input('namedropdown');
```

the `$request->input('namedropdown')` will return an **array** and you try to assign it is returned value to `$employee->namedropdown` which I believe it is **string**.

So you can better do it this way directly:

```
$employee->namedropdown = implode(',', $request->input('namedropdown'));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way

```
   $employee->namedropdown = implode(',', $request->input('namedropdown'));
```